# Angular karma unit test coverage branche

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I have a component with a @Attribute decorator as parameter. I did a test on it but sonar tells me that my builder’s line is not 100% covered on the branch. It highlights me 'green' in yellow. I would have liked to know how to cover it

```
export class CompStatusColorComponent{

  constructor(@Attribute('colorStatut') public colorStatut: string = 'green') { 
    this.colorStatut = colorStatut || 'green';
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the parameter `colorStatut` is undefined, it will be initialized with the default value `'green'`. Therefore, beside providing a specific value, you'll probably also have to provide `null` for parameter `colorStatut` in order to obtain full test coverage.

For further details see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters